# accordion collapse change background color when clicked (collapsed)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am having difficulties of this code. I know this is too easy for you. I have accordion collapse changing background color when clicked(collapsed). the transition of none background color into background color is successfully working fine. the only problem is, I like to deactivate the background color on the first load. here is the code http://jsfiddle.net/gjLxo7be/

```css
.med-header a:not(.collapsed) {
    background-color: #1b3189;
}

a:not(.collapsed) p.contitle1 {
    color: #fff;
}

p.contitle1 {
  color: #1b3189;
  font-size: 25px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  margin: 0 15px;
    text-align: justify;
    font-weight: 500;
  }
  
 .med-header a {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
  }
```

```html
<div id="accordion" role="tablist">
<div class="card m-1 ">
<!--1st-->                              
<div class="panel-default-med">
<div class="med-header" role="tab">
<a data-toggle="collapse" class="text-decoration-none" href="#section-1">
<div class="med-wrap">
 <p class="contitle1">診療方針について</p>
</div>
</a>
</div>
<div class="collapse" id="section-1" data-parent="#accordion">
<div class="card-body">
<p class="context-med">
糖尿病や高血圧等のいわゆる生活習慣病の予防および治療、その合併症である循環器、腎臓疾患等を診療します。 またプライマリ・ケア医として一般内科の他、風邪、呼吸器疾患、骨粗鬆症等の診断や治療も行います。一方で、高齢化に伴って急増している認知症につきましても、もの忘れ外来を開設して診療を行います。                                           
</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div> 
</div>
```

```
or maybe closed the collapse accordion when clicked outside by using javascript? any codes will do.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't believe me, but just do this, add "collapsed" class to the "anchor" tag like this,

```
<a data-toggle="collapse" class="text-decoration-none collapsed" href="#section-1">
```

You are good to go.

Comment: thank you, but how could I auto close when another accordion is clicked?

Comment: You have to put the child accordion with class `accordion-item` inside the parent accordion with class `accordion`

Comment: I don't get it?

Comment: <div class="accordion"> <!-- parent -->
  <div class="accordion-item"> <!-- Child 1 -->
  ...
  </div> 
  <div class="accordion-item"> <!-- Child 2 -->
  ...
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-item"> <!-- Child 3 -->
  ...
  </div>
</div>
... like this

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/shirshak007/1rcybfzv

Comment: you won't believe me but it doesn't work. https://jsfiddle.net/cp6rsqy4/

Comment: what are you you using bootstrap 3 or 4 ?

Comment: I am using bootstrap 3